# Wordpress on Azure can't make database connection

Tags: mysql, wordpress, azure

I'm running Wordpress site on Azure. Site was up alright - slowly, but still. A few days ago it went down when my subscription limits kicked in. After the break I started both the site and database seemed to be working when looking from Azure management portal. But the site gives *Error establishing a database connection* -error.

What I've checked...

- Error comes from the frontend and from the backend (/wp_admin)
- I've checked connection string about million times comparing connection string of the database from the Azure portal, values from the wp-config.php and values from the web app from the Azure portal

I created a following test.php to try connection and making sure it is working. What's even more confusing, this code worked (with real values of course).

```
<?php
$host = "myhostname";
$user = 'myuser';
$password = 'mypassword';
$dbh = @mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
if (!$dbh) {
    echo "Error establishing a database connection";
} else {
    echo "Database connection successful";
}
?>
```

I'm not very experienced with Wordpress and I'm totally lost with this. I'm not sure if Azure is the right place to host Wordpress at all but I'd hate to start building my website again.

I found this very helpful post about issues with connections http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-error-establishing-a-database-connection-in-wordpress/ but it didn't help me either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  I've got the exact same problem.

Comment: Interestingly it looks like clearDB has deleted the wordpress database.  And all the backups are all 1mb - i.e. empty.

Answer (score 2):

I think that [official troubleshooting guidance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/wordpress-troubleshooting-techniques-on-azure-websites/) will be the best place to start. I see that you already check the values and check that the external webservice works. That leaves us with the repair, "retouch" and "Website Service" options. Could you please check if that works?

I assume that by break you mean the next month and credits?

Comment: I read the official guidance earlier (I didn't remember to mention it). It didn't help me either since I tried the Website Service with previous code sample and I've also changed wp-config.php (retouch option). And yes, with break I meant short period of time, site was down because there was no credit left. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: Then repair option?.. The "site from a scratch" option should be last :-)

Comment: I'll try the repair option - although I have same error from both front and back. Starting from scratch might be difficult in Azure anyway. Based on this experience I better do it somewhere else than Azure.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to disable SSL Connection in your MySQL Ressource. To do so go to "Connection secruity" Settings and disable "Enforce SSL connection".

Or add to your wp-config.php

```
define('MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS', MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

Comment: Can we solve it without disbling "Enforce SSL connection" ?

Comment: Does it work when you temporary disable it? If yes you can turn it on again and add this to your wp-config.php define('MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS', MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);